# How to prove composition of two funtions of type $min(c,max (b,x+a))$ is of the same type

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

Suppose i have functions $f(x)=min(c_1,max(b_1,x+a_1))$ and $g(x)=min(c_2,max(b_2,x+a_2))$ , how to prove that $g(f(x))=min(c,max(b,x+a))$ . Here except $x$ all other values are constants.

Motivations of the problem : I was reading editorial of some problem [here](https://atcoder.jp/contests/abc196/editorial/953) but i was not able to understand how 3rd step came from 2nd in the proof.

Comment: This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1944748/329252) could be helpful. I don't mean the answers (which are possibly interesting if you need a proof), but the formula itself in the title (and it works the other way around as well, swapping $\min$ and $\max$)

Answer (score 0):

we have

$$f(x)=min(c_1,max(b_1,x+a_1))$$
$$g(x)=min(c_2,max(b_2,x+a_2))$$

Then it's something like

$$g(f(x))=min(c_2,max(b_2,min(c_1,max(b_1,x+a_1))+a_2))$$

$$=min(min(max(c_1,b_2),c_2),max(max(min(b_1,c_1),b_2),x+a_1+a_2^*))$$

Comment: How did you arrived at last step ?

Comment: @Blazer Just by looking at it and considering what happens if one of the elements is the min or max.